# Data Quality Validation in CSV file

Tags: java

My code is written in Java. I have a web interface where the users are uploading csv files, converted from Excel, with junk data in the file, for example a bunch of comma separated empty rows towards the end of the file after the rows with actual data ended. I want to prevent users from uploading such files. I am using BufferedReader to read the file. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: It's pretty difficult to guess what kind of solution you need if you don't provide any code / technologies / models that you're using. Maybe SuperCsv (java library) will do the job. Check this [tutorial](https://turreta.com/2016/11/12/java-validate-csv-using-supercsv-with-custom-csvcolumnprocessor/)

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    String row = br.readLine();
    String retValue = "false";

    if (row == null)
    {
        retValue = "false";
    }
    else {
        while ((row = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] columns = row.split(",");
            retValue = "false";

            for (int j = 0; j < columns.length; j++)
            {
                if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(columns[j]) == true)
                {
                    retValue = "true";  
                    break;
                }
            } 
            if (retValue == "false")
                break;
        }
    }
    br.close();
    return retValue;
```